# How to reuse a function in javascript with different variables

Tags: javascript

I have a set of buttons, which when clicked trigger a function which toggles their ID to an array called `MyArray`

```
function AddToArray(a, v) {
 
 var v = this.id
 var a = myArray
  
    var i = a.indexOf(v);
    if (i === -1)
        a.push(v);
    else
        a.splice(i,1);
}
```

I want to use this same function for a different set of buttons. Instead of toggling their IDs to `MyArray`, I wish to toggle them to `MySecondArray`

At the moment, I simple have two separate functions, but it seems wrong to repeat code.

I considered adding a data-attribute to the buttons with a value of `MyArray` or `MySecondArray` and then turning this string into a variable to push to the relevant array. I understand though that using functions such as `eval()` can be insecure.

Therefore, I am wondering what the best way to do this is, in terms of reusing functions in general?

Comment: That's exactly what parameters are for. It allows you to apply a function to different values. How is the function currently called?

Comment: Make `myArray` a parameter of the function and pass in the value you want?  Though this function is already pretty strange in that the first thing it does is shadow any values that were passed to it.

Comment: `var a = myArray` does not make sense when you have a in the function declaration. Instead remove the line and a IS myArry OR MySecondArray if you pass it as first parameter

Comment: You're passing in arguments, then overriding them. Instead of assigning a and v, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toggleToArray(arr, id) {
    const i = arr.indexOf(id);
    return i === -1 ? [...arr, id] : arr.filter(val => val !== id);
}

// add if id does not exist
const myArr = toggleToArray(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd');
console.log('toggltoarray.js: 8  myArr ', myArr);

// remove if exists
const myArr1 = toggleToArray(myArr, 'd');
console.log('toggltoarray.js: 12  myArr1 ', myArr1);
```